# Android: Unable to access a local website over HTTPS

Tags: android, html, ssl

I am trying to access a locally hosted website and get its HTML source to parse. I have few questions:

1) Can I use "https://An IP ADDRESS HERE" as a valid URL to try and access. I do not want to make changes in the /etc/hosts file so I want to do it this way.

2) I cannot get the html, since it is giving me Handshake exceptions and Certificate issues. I have tried a lot of help available over the web , but am not successful.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
    String response = "";
    String finalresponse="";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\User\\*" );
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "" );
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
            };

            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }


            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://172.27.224.133");

                HttpsURLConnection con =(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                con.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
                finalresponse=readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return finalresponse;
        }

        private String readStream(InputStream in) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        } 


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(finalresponse);
        }
    }

    public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "https://172.27.224.133" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `https://local-ip-address` to access an SSL protected web page is that this will most likely lead to an issue with the browser trusting the web site's SSL certificate.

This is because the browser will attempt to validate the SSL certificate by checking that the host name being used in the HTTPS URL matches the `CN=` host name contained inside the SSL certificate.

**Updated to remove reference to localhost (I originally thought that locally hosted web site meant on the same server as the browser, which with Android is obviously not the case) :**

You can avoid this validate error by changing your local host table to include the fully qualified host name contained in the SSL certificate and associating that name with the specific IP address you want to use.

**Alternatives to hard-coding IP address in /etc/hosts**

If you have control over how the SSL certificate is created you can add additional host names and even IP addresses to your certificate using `Subject Alternate Names` or SAN.  This may be a viable option if you are using a self-signed certificate.

However, if your locally hosted web site is also accessed from the Internet you are more than likely using a purchased SSL certificate and hard-coding IP addresses into such a certificate will most likely lead to a support issue over time as internal IP address can change over time requiring repurchasing an SSL certificate.

Another option might be to hard-code your internal IP address into the DNS server that the mobile device is using if you have control over that server.