# Can't call HTTPS content on a website to android app

Tags: java, android, git

**Hello I need Help**

I am trying to pull content from this [Website](https://www.compasshb.com/api/v1/passages).

It has Json and Html in it. What I need is to parse the html content from this website and put into my android app as a string. I have been at this for weeks now. How do you do this? I am using Android Studio, if you would like to clone my repository, go right ahead, here is the [Link](https://github.com/jdog1218/United-App.git).

I have so much content that it is redundant for me to paste all of the code in here. If you want me to, I will with an answer. I have been looking up answers for this but all of them failed or they weren't on my topic like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386618/android-unable-to-access-a-local-website-over-https). Or this [one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435447/android-webview-not-caching-https-content).

Thanks So much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Java class EasyHttpClient and copy this code:

```
/*
* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
* or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
* distributed with this work for additional information
* regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
* to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
* "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
* with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
* software distributed under the License is distributed on an
* "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
* KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
* specific language governing permissions and limitations
* under the License.
*/

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HeaderElement;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;


/**
 * Easy to use Http and Https client, that transparently adds gzip compression
 * and ignores all Https certificates. It can also be used for using credentials
 * in your connection.
 *
 * This class was created for Android applications, where the appropriate apache libraries
 * are already available. If you are developing for another platform, make sure
 * to add the httpclient, httpcore and commons-logging libs to your buildpath.
 * They can be downloaded from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
 *
 * <code><br/>
 EasyHttpClient client = new EasyHttpClient();<br/>
 System.out.println(client.get("https://encrypted.google.com/"));<br/>
 * </code>
 *
 * @author match2blue software development GmbH
 * @author RenŽ Fischer, Ulrich Scheller
 */
public class EasyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
    /**
     * Default http port
     */
    private final static int HTTP_PORT = 80;

    /**
     * Default https port
     */
    private final static int HTTPS_PORT = 443;

    protected int lastStatusCode;

    protected String lastReasonPhrase;

    /**
     * Default constructor that initializes gzip handling. It adds the
     * Accept-Encoding gzip flag and also decompresses the response from the server.
     */
    public EasyHttpClient() {
        addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            public void process(final HttpRequest request,
                                final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                if (!request.containsHeader("Accept-Encoding")) {
                    request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
                }
            }
        });

        addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
            public void process(final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Header ceheader = entity.getContentEncoding();
                if (ceheader != null) {
                    for (HeaderElement headerElement : ceheader.getElements()) {
                        if (headerElement.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                            response.setEntity(new GzipEntityWrapper(response.getEntity()));
                            lastStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                            lastReasonPhrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Constructor which handles credentials for the connection (only if username and password are set)
     *
     * param username
     * param password
     */
    public EasyHttpClient(String username, String password) {
        if(username != null && password != null) {
            UsernamePasswordCredentials c = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
            BasicCredentialsProvider cP = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            cP.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, c);
            setCredentialsProvider(cP);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function that creates a ClientConnectionManager which can handle http and https.
     * In case of https self signed or invalid certificates will be accepted.
     */
    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf-8");
        params.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), HTTP_PORT));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), HTTPS_PORT));
        ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return manager;
    }

    /**
     * Make a get request to the specified url
     * @param url
     * @return the response string, null if there was an error
     */
    public String get(String url) {
        HttpGet getReq = new HttpGet(url);
        InputStream content = null;
        try {
            content = execute(getReq).getEntity().getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = content.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bout.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            content.close();
            return bout.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

//    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        EasyHttpClient client = new EasyHttpClient();
//        System.out.println(client.get("https://encrypted.google.com/"));
//    }
}

class GzipEntityWrapper extends HttpEntityWrapper {
    public GzipEntityWrapper(HttpEntity wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getContent() throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        return new GZIPInputStream(wrappedEntity.getContent());
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        return -1; // unknown
    }
}


/**
 * This socket factory will create ssl socket that accepts self signed
 * certificate
 *
 * author olamy
 * version $Id: EasySSLSocketFactory.java 765355 2009-04-15 20:59:07Z evenisse$
 * since 1.2.3
 */
class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {
    private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

    private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null,
                    new TrustManager[] { new TrivialTrustManager() }, null);
            return context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
        if (this.sslcontext == null) {
            this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
        }
        return this.sslcontext;
    }

    /**
     * @see SocketFactory#connectSocket(Socket,
     * String, int, InetAddress, int,
     * HttpParams)
     */
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port,
                                InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

        if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
// we need to bind explicitly
            if (localPort < 0) {
                localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
            }
            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress,
                    localPort);
            sslsock.bind(isa);
        }

        sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
        sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
        return sslsock;
    }

    /**
     * @see SocketFactory#createSocket()
     */
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    /**
     * @see SocketFactory#isSecure(Socket)
     */
    public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(Socket,
     * String, int, boolean)
     */
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                               boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host,
                port, autoClose);
    }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass() == EasyHttpClient.class.getClass());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
    }
}


class TrivialTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

And in your doInBackground use this code for get the jsonString:

```
EasyHttpClient client = new EasyHttpClient();

String jsonString = client.get("https://www.compasshb.com/api/v1/passages");
```

And do anything what you want with your json string, don't forget call your AsyncTask by this way:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought it was something to do with the certificates but didn't know how to do it

Comment: It actually hasn't solved my problem completly, when i try to set text view of the html, it doesn't set on excute. I will update my repository soon.

Comment: In debug it is found as the string but doesnt set text view

Comment: Well, you need to do other question for this, share the part of code that set text in texview and share the logcat. This question is close if the answer that you need. Correct?